# Want To Check Plan is Expired Or Not

Tags: sql

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `user_plan` WHERE `plan_start_date` >='" . $today . "' && `plan_end_date`<='" . $today . "' && `user_id`='" . $user_id . "';
$db->sql($sql);
$result = $db->getResult();

Comment: And how can we help you with this task?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user_plan WHERE plan_end_date<NOW() && user_id='" . $user_id . "'; 
$db->sql($sql);
$result = $db->getResult();
```